# split lines during concatenation

Tags: unix, filter

I have a list of files, exactly 14.000 files. Each file contains just one line and many columns (a file can contain 1 line and 9.000 columns). I would like to concatenate all that files in one file. Since each file contains 18 header lines I used "tail". The problem is that the concatenation fails because sometimes a line (probably because it is too long) is split and written on a new line. In this way I cannot rebuild the original output because on 14,000 files it is impossible to check where the split occurred. Can anyone help me to overcome this problem?

Just an example of two files after removing the first 18 header lines:

```
FLD1/file.txt:
...18 lines of header here...
PITPNM1 MARCH1  0.076739 MARCH5 0.134571 

FLD2/file.txt:
...18 lines of header here...
SEPT11 0.109543 DEC1 0.0536367  201205_at 0.0582265 202881_x_at 0.224719
```

what I expect is:

```
PITPNM1 MARCH1  0.076739 MARCH5 0.134571 
SEPT11  0.109543 DEC1 0.0536367 201205_at 0.0582265 202881_x_at 0.224719
```

Instead, the output it gives wrongly is this:

```
PITPNM1 MARCH1  0.076739 MARCH5 0.134571    
SEPT11  0.109543 DEC1 0.0536367 201205_at    
0.0582265 202881_x_at   0.224719
```

it splits the second line in two sublines.

Comment: You contradict yourself. Does each of the 14000 files contain one line or 18 lines or even more? Please be **exact** and provide an example with two files.

Comment: sorry, you're right. Each file contains totally 19 lines but the first 18 lines are only header lines I'm not interested in. I need just the last line, so one line per file.

Comment: Which program do you use which splits the lines?

Comment: Is there a way (a pattern) to recognize the header lines? E.g. if the 18 lines each start with some common string like `#`, it could be as simple as `grep '^[^#]' */file.txt`.

Comment: Before your suggestions I used: tail -n+18 FLD*/file.txt >> concatenation_file.txt;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try extracting line 19 e.g. with this script, run in the directory where your FLD1, FLD2 folders are.

```
 #!/bin/sh
 find . -name file.txt |
 while read -r file; do
   awk 'NR==19' $file
 done > resultfile
```

But note that the definition of a *line* in Unix says that it can't be arbitrarily long. If awk on your system truncates long lines or splits them, use perl, i.e.

```
 perl -ne 'print if ($. == 19)' $file   # instead of awk above
```

Comment: Hi Jens, I'm trying to run  your code. Nevertheless I have another problem. The 14.000 files are stored in this way: FLD1 contains file.txt I'm interested in, FLD2 contains file.txt and so on. So, each time the folder name changes, but the file name I'm interested in is the same. Now I need a way to go in/out each folder each time and run the code you suggest me. Could you suggest me a way to do this? I'm new in Unix programming. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Okay, now we're getting somewhere. I have modified the script to take folders into account. For a test, try running `find . -name file.txt` to see if it finds the right files.

Comment: For a Unix novice, the `find` utility is a monster at first, but it pays to understand its power. I warmly recommend reading the manual with `man find`. If you read and understand it, you're ready to become the next Unix guru! Welcome to a fascinating operating system (By the way, which one? What does `uname -sr` say?)

Comment: Hi Jens, I really would like to become the next Unix (Darwin 10.8.0) guru even if it seems to me more than a monster! A pletora of manuals and tutorials are available, sometimes very simple and sometimes very difficult but as someone said I "persist and do not desist!"

Comment: As you can see, the solution depends very much on your input file format. Can you describe the headers in a way which sets them apart from the data? Maybe the data always starts with a capital letter, while the headers do not. Then it would be as simple as `grep '^[A-Z]' */file.txt`.

Comment: the header lines start all with ">". Each header line contains the parameters setting used before run the algorithm. For example one of the 18 lines appears like: > Kernel width 0.292234

Comment: Allright, then I think we have a winner: `grep '^[^>]' */file.txt > concatenation_file.txt`. Does the result contain split lines? The grep command is "output all lines where the first character in a line is not `>`".